# Opencart SEO URL

Tags: php, opencart

My question is, I have installed the SEO component successfully, and its working well but;

On homepage, the Latest Products module shows the url like

> http://www.domain.com/product-21.html

On category page, the product shows the url like

> http://www.domain.com/category/product-21.html

I want to put the category URL in the latest products module so it will be the same as on category page. Does anybody have any ideas about this?

Comment: [This modification](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=5023) does exactly what you want (commercial)

Answer (score 0):

i don't clearly understant what you want to mention
but if you want to edit ur url from http://www.domain.com/category -> http://www.domain.com/category.html there're many way you can edit file .htaccess or in my way you can edit code in seo_url.php like this:
find this code
return $url_info['scheme'] . '://' . $url_info['host'] . (isset($url_info['port']) ? ':' . $url_info['port'] : '') . str_replace('/index.php', '', $url_info['path']) . $url . $query;
and replace with this 
return $url_info['scheme'] . '://' . $url_info['host'] . (isset($url_info['port']) ? ':' . $url_info['port'] : '') . str_replace('/index.php', '', $url_info['path']) . $url . $query.'html';
(if you've edit your product seo word like product.html pls re move .html postfix because this will cause product.html.html)

Answer (score 0):

Go to that product form in the admin panel ,in the data section you will find 'SEO Keyword:' option add value the it will changed automaticly in the home page link.